# How to display longtext data as it is in mysql

Tags: php, html, database

This might be a simple question but i can't seem to find it anywhere.

When I store data from a topic or a comment in the database the message is stored in a longtext, however the longtext shows fine in the table (it shows enters and multiple spaces) but when i retrieve the data with a simple code like `echo $commentmessage;` it shows the data without any proper enters or extra spaces. I tried using the `<pre>` function but it gives me more trouble than i want to.

Help is much appreciated

Comment: In what way is the <pre> tag giving you trouble? It seems to be just what you're asking for otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) before printing the records. Something like this

```
echo nl2br($commentmessage);
```